# glInterleavedArrays() generates GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION

Tags: c++, opengl

When I trying to use glInterleavedArrays() I always get "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION" error.

```
GLuint bufid;
glGenBuffers(1, &bufid);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufid);
glInterleavedArrays(GL_C4F_N3F_V3F, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

What's wrong with this code?

**Update**

`glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER)` and `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER )` both returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`.

Comment: Don't use the address of `a` as the data pointer to this function. That is the address of that variable on the stack, and is ***very*** unlikely to point to a valid location in the VBO `bufid` (which has no data allocated at the moment, I should point out). This particular error has nothing to do with your vertex array, and everything to do with the setup of an FBO.

Comment: You do not seem to be getting the point I was making about VBOs. You are passing the address of client memory, yet you have a VBO bound. You are supposed to pass an offset into the VBO's memory, usually **0** for an interleaved array. But your actual problem is related to an FBO with invalid state, in other words check [`glCheckFramebufferStatus (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml). Interleaved arrays are deprecated, by the way - you should just use separate color, normal and vertex pointers with an appropriate stride.

Comment: `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` returned `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`. So, I just can't do anything with it and I should use `glVertexPointer()` and other separate functions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is because of the interleaved array? There are tons of reasons for invalid framebuffer operations. But this seems to be an unlikely cause.

Even if the framebuffer is complete it can still generate invalid operations, like enabling stencil without a stencil buffer.

You can replicate interleaved arrays with regular ones quite easily. Does the error persist?

Comment: I have never seen enabling stencil/depth test without a stencil/depth buffer generate this error. The error was only introduced to OpenGL when FBOs were added (3.0), and it indicates that an incomplete FBO is in use. I am beginning to think that the ***actual*** error is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` and this is a core profile context -- because this is a deprecated function it will generate `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.